# send http request from IIS to GCM using java

Tags: java, json, iis, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send Json message from my [java application server] to [GCM]:
**the java server app located on IIS server (Windows server 2008 R2).**
here is my function:

```
public static String post(String apiKey, String json){

        try{

       URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type:", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization:", "key="+apiKey); // apiKey is valid browser apiKey.
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
              wr.writeUTF(json);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
 /*I've deleted the respond check from the question*/
}
```

but I fail to send!, and does not get any message or exception.

I think that the server itself doesnt let me send http requests!
is this true? how to solve?

Comment: To begin with, you should be using a Server key, not a Browser key. Any logs printed out by your app server?

Comment: I tried  Server key and Browser key, not sending and no logs! no error message or respond!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Sender and Message objects instead. The sample GCM server code uses those. Sample server code can be seen [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java).

If you really insist on handling the connection yourself, you can look at the underlying `HttpURLConnection` implementation of the Sender object [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.java#565).

It does appear that there are certain differences between the Sender code and your request properties. Hope this helps.